# Exclude Xcode header search path

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, carthage

I am using Carthage and as part of that have the following structure:

```
$SRCROOT
  -Code
  -Carthage
    -Build
    -Checkouts
```

Everything runs fine, but upon a crash, I get errors like these in debug console.

```
error: /Users/alex/Desktop/x/Carthage/Build/iOS/CocoaLumberjack.framework/Headers/DDAbstractDatabaseLogger.h:30:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'DDAbstractDatabaseLogger'
@interface DDAbstractDatabaseLogger : DDAbstractLogger {
^

/Users/alex/Desktop/x/Carthage/Checkouts/FewPods/Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Classes/DDAbstractDatabaseLogger.h:30:12: note: previous definition is here
@interface DDAbstractDatabaseLogger : DDAbstractLogger {
```

I am able to resolve by moving the Checkouts folder elsewhere, but that makes things somewhat inconvenient.

Any other way I can make Xcode ignore everything under `Checkouts`?

Comment: Actually it is not clear why/how Carthage Checkouts got into your target dependencies... try to find if there is ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS somewhere remained and remove it or set to NO... can't they be added somehow accidentally?

Comment: Hi. I thought that so searched build settings for "Checkouts" directory and tried a bunch of flags. ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS is set to NO (Only set to YES in `Carthage/Checkouts/facebook-ios-sdk/samples/FBSDKPlacesSample/FBSDKPlacesSample.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` which should not matter right)

Comment: Are you using multiple targets???

Answer (score 0):

This same issue was with me, here are steps that i have followed.

1) open your project in show in Finder.

2) click pod project [image: click on Show Package Contents]

3) open pbx file into TextEditor [image: Open File in textEditor]

4) search for "CocoaLumberjack" you will find it multiple times in your project. remove it. save change and run code again. you will find no more issue.

Comment: Can you please explain the idea behind this fix? I do not have a Pods.xcodeproj as such as I use carthage. I have bundled a few dependencies imported via cocoapods under FewPods carthage dependency, which includes CocoaLumberJack. It's imported via carthage as a framework, so I can not really remove it from the main project.pbxproj as it won't compile.